# Prisma with NodeJS and Express runtime error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, prisma

When running the server, I get `[ERROR] 14:48:46 Error: Cannot find module './runtime/library'`. The top of the stack trace is in the `prisma` directory.

After running `npx prisma generate`, the `prisma/@prisma/client/runtime` directory remains empty.

I appear to be following the correct setup process. I cannot find anyone else with this error on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

```js
generator client {
     provider = "prisma-client-js"
     output   = "./client"
}
```

You can do it this way too, especially  when you have multiple Prisma schemas
Note: it will be generated in a client folder inside "prisma folder" where the schema is stored.prisma file is.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the generator should not point to the `./prisma` directory. Instead I ended up with

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  output        = "../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}
```

And I updated all the imports to `@prisma/client` instead of the import that the output of `npx prisma generate` suggests.